# Jest: Expect function which was returned from another mocked function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

My code is like this:

```
async function A() {
    const myObj = await b();
    myObj.create();
}
```

In my jest file, I mock the function b() like this:

```
b.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        create: () => '',
    }
}
```

Now I want to check if myObj.create() was called or not. How do I do that?
Something like:

```
await A();
expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of return a anonymous object, you have to return a mock object. With the mocked object, you can control the function `create` has to call or not.

```
// Mocked object with `create` property is a mock function
const mockedMyObj = {
  create: jest.fn(),
};

// b is a async function, we just mock the return value. 
b.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(mockedMyObj));

// expect
await A();
expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled();
// now you can verify the `create` function
expect(mockedMyObj.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
```